# How to update value of an immutable list by iterating through it

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

Here I have an immutable list.I need to update isReq object to false for all the objects except the one having the id 2.

```
[
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Ram',
    'Details': {
        'isReq': true
    }
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'dev',
    'Details': {
        'isReq': true
    }
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'joe',
    'Details': {
        'isReq': true
    }
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and add an if-else branch:

```
list.map(item => {
  if (item.id === 2) {
    return item
  } else {
    return { ...item, Details : {isReq': false} }
  }
}
```

Here we use the object spread operator to update the item, but you could also use `Object.assign` or something different entirely.

Comment: while dealing with normal javascript objects, that would do it, but here I was refering to the immutable

Comment: You're using `Immutable.Record` then? Updating that is even easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my problem here, but doesn't  know if its the optimal way to do it.

```
let selectedId = 2;
        let arr = fromJS(
            [{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'Ram', 'Details': { 'isReq': true } },
            { 'id': 2, 'name': 'dev', 'Details': { 'isReq': true } },
            { 'id': 3, 'name': 'joe', 'Details': { 'isReq': true } }]);

        let newarr = arr.map(function (val: any, index: any) {
            if (val.get('id') === selectedId) {
                return val.setIn(['Details', 'isReq'], true);
            } else {
                return val.setIn(['Details', 'isReq'], false);
            }
        });
```